# How can i integrate firebase authentication with external database like mySQL in my android project?

Tags: android, mysql, database, firebase, kotlin

i'm about to make an android application that each user have it's own data restored in the database.. but i want my user auth restored in firebase, while the details data is in mySQL. is it possible to implementing it in android? or maybe you guys have any solutions for my project?

features on my application

- authentication
- profile (edit profile, user can post card photo like feeds on instagram)
- chatting feature
- home (recyclerview that display users post card )
- category (recyclerview based on category)
- search feature

Comment: Are you willing to try [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) or the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) for your use case? It will make your life easier.

Comment: which one do u recommend for my Kotlin project? since my main feature is that user can post, but i want the data item post is on mysql while the detail of user profile is on firebase auth

Comment: I recommend Cloud Firestore and I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Comment: thank you sm for the explanation.. i'll definitely reconsider it